# math symbol like a dot under the `\simeq`

Tags: symbols

I need to use the following symbol in topology:
[image]

My attempt is to use the `accents` package as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\simeqdot}{\mathrel{\underaccent{\cdot}{\mathord\simeq}}}

\begin{document}

$a\simeqdot b\quad A\simeqdot B$

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]
I think there are at least two things which need to be adjusted further.

- Looking carefully, one can find that the dot is not horizontally centered.
- The symbol produced by `\simeqdot` should be raised a little.

Your suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lower level commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\simeqdot}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\simeqdot@\relax}}
\newcommand{\simeqdot@}[2]{%
  \vtop{%
    \offinterlineskip % no space between lines
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr % one centered column
      $\m@th#1\simeq$\cr % \simeq
      \noalign{\sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mkern1.5mu$}\vspace{\wd\z@}}% some space
      $\m@th#1.$\cr % the dot
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A\simeqdot B \scriptstyle \quad A\simeqdot B
\]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{$\simeqdot$} % show the bounding box
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you replace `\vtop` with `\vcenter`, you get

[image]